# Angular - Constructor item is "undefined" in function

Tags: html, angular, typescript, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I'm trying to use my data service in a component, but when I click the button it gives error and says data service is undefined.

Here's my component file:

```
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource: any;
  priority: any[];
  e: any;

  constructor(public dataService: DataService) {
      // data source stuff...
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.dataService) //successfully shows DataService object
  }

  addToCart(e) {
    console.log(e.row.data["Task_Subject"]);
    console.log(this.dataService) // undefined?!?
    this.dataService.addItem(e.row.data["Task_Subject"])
  }
}
```

And the HTML Template of Component:

```
<h2 class="content-block">Products</h2>

<dx-data-grid class="dx-card wide-card" [dataSource]="dataSource" [showBorders]="false" [focusedRowEnabled]="true"
  [focusedRowIndex]="0" [columnAutoWidth]="true" [columnHidingEnabled]="true">

  <dxo-paging [pageSize]="10"></dxo-paging>
  <dxo-pager [showPageSizeSelector]="false" [showInfo]="true"></dxo-pager>
  <dxo-filter-row [visible]="true"></dxo-filter-row>

  <dxi-column dataField="Task_ID" [width]="90" [hidingPriority]="2">
  </dxi-column>
  <dxi-column dataField="Task_Subject" [width]="190" caption="Subject" [hidingPriority]="8">
  </dxi-column>
  <dxi-column dataField="Task_Status" caption="Status" [hidingPriority]="6">
  </dxi-column>
  <dxi-column dataField="Task_Priority" caption="Priority" [hidingPriority]="5">
    <dxo-lookup [dataSource]="priority" valueExpr="value" displayExpr="name">
    </dxo-lookup>
  </dxi-column>
  <dxi-column dataField="ResponsibleEmployee.Employee_Full_Name" caption="Assigned To" [allowSorting]="false"
    [hidingPriority]="7">
  </dxi-column>
  <dxi-column caption="Actions" type="buttons" [hidingPriority]="0">
    <dxi-button icon="plus" [onClick]="addToCart">Action</dxi-button>
  </dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

When I click the button on 'dxi-button' addToCart() function runs. In ngOnInit function, the data service shows up, but in addToCart function, console logging data service gives me undefined.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using DevExtreme by the way.

Comment: DevExtreme does something weird with nested components.  Usually you would use `()` for event binding.  My guess is they are not properly setting 'this', console.log 'this' and see what it is. [docs](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Angular_Components/Component_Configuration_Syntax/)

Comment: this library you're using seems to have you pass the function instead of doing a traditional event binding. This is a giant red flag to me and implies that this library is poorly integrated with angular, and as such, you may want to avoid using it in an angular context.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat thank you, I console.log 'this' and it gave me object like this one {cssClass: undefined,icon: "plus",name: undefined,onClick: ƒ addToCart(),text:undefined}

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you call your function isn't in the angular context

Try to do a `console.log(this)` and if the object isn't of type ProductsComponent then you aren't in the angular context anymore

If that's the case you can change the way you call the onClick function inside your html template

maybe something like

```
(onClick)="addToCart(item)"
```

Comment: This way doesn't work, because my way is DevExtreme way on documentations. When I tried actual angular contexts, it gives me "button.onclick.call is not a function" error. This is only way to let the button work but... I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: @MertCanBilgiç can you provide us a stackblitz with the usecase ?

Comment: from what I can see in the documentation, you can bind a (onClick) function inside a devExtreme component

Answer (score 1):

I fixed with a little trick, posting the answer for another people. Devexpress change the scope of "this". For solving that, I just added

```
this.addToCart = this.addToCart.bind(this);
```

into constructor and now I can use this.dataService properly! Thank you for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [callback function docs](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Angular_Components/Component_Configuration_Syntax/#Callback_Functions) for devextreme components, the binding is done in a very un-angular way.

In angular and for top-level components you can use the `()` binding.  Since nested components use the `[]` binding syntax, you need to pass it a function that is bound to the object you wish to be 'this' inside the function.  It recommends doing that in your constructor:

> Callback functions are executed outside the component's context. If the context is important, explicitly bind the callback function to it in the constructor.

```js
  constructor(public dataService: DataService) {
      // data source stuff...
      this.addToCart.bind(this);
  }
```